# Как через ссылку на сайте открыть ПО на компьютере?

Tags: javascript, php, html, windows, nginx

В локальной сети есть сервер( сервер по роли, по сути обычный пк), на нем nginx, и собственно сайт.
Все компьютеры на Windows 10, включая сам сервер. Браузеры на хромиуме и огнелис.
Сайт представляет из себя просто иконки с нужными ресурсами(ссылками на сайты), но есть потребность добавить иконки на ПО установленное на компах пользователей. А так же на проводник, чтобы он открывался или в браузере, или открывалось приложение проводника в нужном месте, например //share/some_folder.
Как можно реализовать?

Comment: напишите подходит ли Вам решение приведенное в ответе и если нет то почему, и какие варианты Вы пробовали сами.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)

Comment: @XelaNimed если большой парк машин и внезапная политика АД, это не лучший способ.

Comment: А схема `file:///` не пашет?

Comment: @don Rumata, К сожалению таким образом скачивается сам файл.

Comment: Другого способа нет. Причём здесь парк машин и политики? Для открытия приложения по ссылке, это приложение должно быть установлено на машине. Регистрацию обработчика своей схемы URI нужно выполнять при установке этого приложения. В любом случае Вам нужно изменять приложение и добавлять в него нужное поведение, будь то синхронизация иконок или передача данных в приложение посредством URI.

Answer (score -2):

Для запуска надо написать скрипты в PHP, если у вас бэк на нем

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.exec.php сюда заходили?

Comment: Заходил. Соль в том, чтобы все открывалось на ПК клиента... Поэтому exec и system тут не помощники.